# Auto layout errors when adding "line" to view on iOS 7

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have seven elements side by side for which auto layout should calculate its width and the parent view should determine it's height. On this parent view I want to add a line to separate the areas more clearly. When adding this line (a UIView with a background color) I get some black bars at the right side of the parent view (container for the seven elements) and also one of the other views.

[image: Showing line and black error produced by auto layout]

If I don't add this line it does work fine on iOS 7. On iOS 8 it does work even when the line is present. These are my auto layout constraints for the line:

`V:[line(==0.5)]|` and `H:|-0-[line]-0-|`

The seven labels have the following constraints:

`H:|-0-[first][second(==first)][third(==first)][fourth(==first)][fifth(==first)][sixt(==first)][seventh(==first)]-0-|`

and

`V:|[first]|`

and so on.

Why does adding the line not work for iOS 7 auto layout system? How can I add my line correctly?

**Edit:**

My seven labels are in a container view - the *header*. The *header* is placed together with a collection view (added as child view controller) on a normal view controller. This "main" view controller (or container if you want) has the following constraints:

`H:|-0-[header]-0-|` - header holding the seven labels
`H:|-0-[monthView]-0-|` - collection view
`H:|-0-[toolbar]-0-|` - toolbar
`V:|-0-[header(==15)][monthView][toolbar(==44)]-0-|` - vertical position all three elements

I got it managed to get an auto layout trace once all views where loaded:

```
*<UIWindow:0x7897f370> - AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT
|   *<UILayoutContainerView:0x78eb09f0>
|   |   *<UINavigationTransitionView:0x78db1b50>
|   |   |   *<UIViewControllerWrapperView:0x78dbb400>
|   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x7897c780>
|   |   |   |   |   *<MonthView_MonthViewHeader:0x78ddd600>
|   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x78ddede0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x78de29e0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x78de2a90>
|   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x78de2bc0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x78de2de0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x78de3140>
|   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x78de3360>
|   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78de3580>
|   |   |   |   |   *<UICollectionViewControllerWrapperView:0x78ebdd00>
|   |   |   |   |   |   *<UICollectionView:0x795c1a00>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<MonthView_MonthViewCell:0x78ed1270>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0x78d2cab0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d2d660>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d2c8b0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x78d2c6a0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<MonthView_MonthViewCell:0x78d29450>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0x78d290d0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d293f0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d29020>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x78d28f10>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<MonthView_MonthViewCell:0x78d27ec0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0x78d27c30>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d27e60>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d27b80>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x78d27a70>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<MonthView_MonthViewCell:0x78d26a20>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0x78d26790>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d269c0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d266e0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x78d265d0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<MonthView_MonthViewCell:0x78d253e0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0x78d25170>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d25380>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d250c0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x78d24fb0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<MonthView_MonthViewCell:0x78d23f60>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0x78d23cd0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d23f00>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d23c20>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x78d23b10>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<MonthView_MonthViewCell:0x78d1ed90>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0x78d1eb00>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d1ed30>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d1ea50>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x78d1e940>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<MonthView_MonthViewCell:0x78d1d860>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0x78d1d610>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d1d800>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d1d560>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x78d1d450>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<MonthView_MonthViewCell:0x78d1c3f0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0x78d1c160>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d1c390>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d1c0b0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x78d1bfa0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<MonthView_MonthViewCell:0x78d1af40>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0x78d1acb0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d1aee0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d1ac00>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x78d1aaf0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<MonthView_MonthViewCell:0x78d19a90>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0x78d19800>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d19a30>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d19750>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x78d19640>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<MonthView_MonthViewCell:0x78d185e0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0x78d18350>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d18580>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d182a0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x78d18190>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<MonthView_MonthViewCell:0x78d170c0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0x78d16e60>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d17060>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d16db0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x78d16ca0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<MonthView_MonthViewCell:0x78d15c40>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0x78d159b0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d15be0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d15900>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x78d157f0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<MonthView_MonthViewCell:0x78d14790>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0x78d14500>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d14730>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d14450>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x78d14340>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<MonthView_MonthViewCell:0x78d132e0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0x78d13050>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d13280>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d12fa0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x78d12e90>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<MonthView_MonthViewCell:0x78d11e30>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0x78d11ba0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d11dd0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d11af0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x78d119e0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<MonthView_MonthViewCell:0x78d10980>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0x78d106f0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d10920>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d10640>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x78d10530>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<MonthView_MonthViewCell:0x78d0f4d0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0x78d0f240>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d0f470>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d0f190>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x78d0f080>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<MonthView_MonthViewCell:0x78d0e020>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0x78d0dd90>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d0dfc0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d0dce0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x78d0dbd0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<MonthView_MonthViewCell:0x78d0c960>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0x78d0c740>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d17190>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d0c690>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x78d0c580>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<MonthView_MonthViewCell:0x78d0b520>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0x78d0b290>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d0b4c0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d0b1e0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x78d0b0d0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<MonthView_MonthViewCell:0x78d0a070>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0x78d09de0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d0a010>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d09d30>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x78d09c20>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<MonthView_MonthViewCell:0x78d08bc0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0x78d08930>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d08b60>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d08880>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x78d08770>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<MonthView_MonthViewCell:0x78d07710>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0x78d07480>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d076b0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d073d0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x78d072c0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<MonthView_MonthViewCell:0x78d06150>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0x78d05ec0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d060f0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d05e10>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x78d05d00>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<MonthView_MonthViewCell:0x78d04ca0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0x78d04a10>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d04c40>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d04960>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<Circle:0x78d3c6b0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x78d04850>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<MonthView_MonthViewCell:0x78d037f0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0x78d03560>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d03790>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d034b0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x78d033a0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<MonthView_MonthViewCell:0x78d02270>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0x78d01fe0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d02210>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d01f30>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x78d01e20>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<MonthView_MonthViewCell:0x78d00dc0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0x78d00b30>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78d00d60>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78e64000>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x78ed2dd0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<MonthView_MonthViewCell:0x78ed3e60>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0x78ed4130>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78ed3f00>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78ed41e0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x78ed42a0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<MonthView_MonthViewCell:0x78ed5310>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0x78ed55e0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78ed53b0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78ed5690>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x78ed5750>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<MonthView_MonthViewCell:0x78ed67c0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0x78ed6a90>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78ed6860>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78ed6b40>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x78ed6c00>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<MonthView_MonthViewCell:0x78ed7eb0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0x78ed8180>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78ed7f50>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78ed8230>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x78ed82f0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<MonthView_MonthViewCell:0x78ed9360>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0x78ed9630>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78ed9400>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78ed96e0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x78ed97a0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<MonthView_SectionHeader:0x78edb330>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78eda940>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78edc740>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78edc7a0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78edca50>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78edcae0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78edcb70>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x78edcc00>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x78edcc90>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIImageView:0x78df2690>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIImageView:0x78df1c40>
|   |   |   |   |   |   *<MonthView_SectionOverlay:0x78dc8fd0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<GradientView:0x78dcc780>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x78dd3ea0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   *<_UILayoutGuide:0x78dc8a20> - AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT
|   |   |   |   |   *<MonthView_Toolbar:0x78de7540>
|   |   |   |   |   |   <_UIToolbarBackground:0x78de7c40>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   <_UIBackdropView:0x78d3e940>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <_UIBackdropEffectView:0x78d3e730>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0x78d3e650>
|   |   |   |   |   |   <UIImageView:0x78de8c70>
|   |   |   |   |   |   <UIToolbarTextButton:0x78dfa240>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   <_UIToolbarNavigationButton:0x78df9aa0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIButtonLabel:0x78ef69f0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   <UIToolbarTextButton:0x78dfaa50>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   <_UIToolbarNavigationButton:0x78d3eb00>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIButtonLabel:0x78ef5740>
|   |   <UINavigationBar:0x78eb1ad0>
|   |   |   <_UINavigationBarBackground:0x78eb2170>
|   |   |   |   <_UIBackdropView:0x78db8270>
|   |   |   |   |   <_UIBackdropEffectView:0x78dba8d0>
|   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0x78dbb3a0>
|   |   |   |   <UIImageView:0x78eb24e0>
|   |   |   <_UINavigationBarBackIndicatorView:0x78eb4f30>
```

[Here](http://www.codeshare.io/UCBtu) you can find the recursive description after the view was loaded.

Comment: Have you set the constraints up through code or through storyboard? If you chose the first way, why did you not try creating the line in the interface builder?

Comment: I'm not using storyboard. All in code.

Comment: Constraints go both ways. Sometimes a constraint between a view and its subviews can result in the parent's views size changing in order to satisfy the constraint. Perhaps it's having trouble dividing the width evenly by seven, so it is resizing the superview. So the question is what constraints does the view have to the main view. Does it have `H:|[container]|` constraints?

Comment: okay, regarding coded constraints i sadly cant help you :/

Comment: @Rob: The question is if my constraints are wrong and what is responsible for the change in size. Interestingly, a not involved view also changes its width (only related with the parent view - the view controller). Yes, the container has this constraint `H:|-0-[header]-0-|`

Comment: @luk2302: Nevertheless, I appreciate your input. In general, I think the constraints in storyboard and code would be very similar.

Comment: I hope so, yes, but i cant read / dont understand the String representation of them.

Comment: Your constraints for all of these seven subviews look fine, but I suspect the problem rests in the constraints for their superview, but you haven't shared that with us, so we can't say. I'd run the app, pause execution, and at `(lldb)` prompt, enter `po [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace]` and make sure you don't have any ambiguous constraints. I'd also update question with `po [[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription]` so we get better feel for all of the moving parts.

Comment: @luk2302: Basically, the height for the labels (first to seventh) is taken from its superview *header*. The labels are pinned to edges (first - left, last - right), are connected to each other (one after another horizontally) and all labels should have the same size. The *line* is also pinned to left/right and has a height of 0.5, whereas it is pinned to the bottom of the container *header*.

Comment: You say the container has `H:|-0-[header]-0-|`. Great. So is the container's superview the view controller's root view? Or is it within a container view, itself? And if so, what constraint does that view have with its superview? Your image suggests that the problem is not the seven subviews, nor their `header`, but rather the `H` constraints of the `header` view's superview.

Comment: @Rob: I'm looking for a solution to get a autolayout trace in Xamarin.iOS, but it seems that I have to write some P/Invoke methods and this will take time if I get it managed. I've edited my answer to explain my setup in more detail.

Comment: The salient detail in this revised question is that you're doing this within a collection view. That adds another level of possible issues. Use different `backgroundColor` for the cell and the collection view and confirm whether this edge on the right side of the screen is part of the cell peaking through or whether it is the collection view's background.

Comment: @Rob: I changed the background color of the collection view. The supplementary view now has this color, but the black area on the side stays the same. I thought the views are independent between each other. And if I remove the line everything works fine. Strange.

Comment: @Rob: Now I added `_autolayoutTrace` and `recursiveDescription`. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'll never find out what is wrong with the auto layout system on iOS 7. But I now use a workaround: Instead of adding the line to the same view like the seven labels I add it to another container. Pseudo-Code:

weekdayHeader = [label1]-[label7]
monthViewHeader = [weekdayHeader][line(==0.5)]

And the *monthViewHeader* is added together with my other views (`UICollectionView`, `UIToolbar`) to my main view controller/container.